# Discord.py Emoji object error with discord's default Unicode emojis

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Simply I am creating a command that takes an [emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji)/[partial emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#partialemoji) argument as an input to the command.

but it seems that discord.py recognizes custom emojis (which are not the default ones in discord) as an emoji/partial emoji object but when I try to give it a default Unicode emoji from discord it gives me a
commands.UserInputError
This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def massreact(ctx, limit: int, reaction : PartialEmoji):
await ctx.message.delete()
async for message in ctx.message.channel.history(limit=limit):
    await message.add_reaction(reaction)
```

For example if i do:

(prefix) 5 (custom emoji, gif or png) **(it works)**

But if I do:

(prefix) 5  **(it doesn't work and as I said it takes it as a commands.UserInputError)**

Note: This hand emoji is a default emoji in discord which is **:ok_hand:**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `async def massreact(ctx, limit: int, reaction : PartialEmoji):`
to -

```
async def massreact(ctx, limit: int, reaction : str):
```

That should work, if it does not, just comment on this answer, would be happy to help.

Comment: that's weird, why did discord.py add these objects then tho
if we can just take the emojis as strings